# how to check for a null value in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to check for a value in a table  to see if it's null.

If so, I just want output to be '0.000'; otherwise, I'd like the actual value which must be converted to a varchar field.

The definition of the column in the database is decimal(10,3).

When I run my below query (pertinent part of the query), I get an error message:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Here is my t-sql syntax that is getting the error. How do I correct it?

```
isnull(nullif(Ryder_Price,'0.000'),convert(varchar(max),Ryder_Price))
```

### EDIT

Here is the full SELECT statement:

```
Select '4'+','
            +','+Case when Country_Code= 1 then 'USA' else 'CAN' End 
            +','+
            +','+isnull(nullif(Ryder_Price,'0.000'),convert(varchar(max),Ryder_Price))
            +','+isnull(nullif(Ryder_Price,'0.000'),convert(varchar(max),Ryder_Price))
            +','+isnull(nullif(Ryder_Price,'0.000'),convert(varchar(max),Ryder_Price))
            +','+
            +','+'01/01/1900'
            +','+'01/01/2099'PartMaster_String
            ,4 ord,part_no 
            , RIGHT('000'+convert(varchar(3),ATA_SYSCode),3)+'-'+RIGHT('000'+convert(varchar(3),ATA_Asmcode),3)+'-'+RIGHT('000'+convert(varchar(3),ATA_Partcode),3) taskstring
            From tbl_CPM_PARTS_MASTER_PTC
```

Comment: check coalesce function

Comment: `case ryder_price is null then '0.0000' else convert(...) end`? Your isnull(nullif makes very little sense... you're isnulling the ENTIRE expression.

Comment: I don't see any way that bit of code alone can cause the error you are getting.   I suspect it is interacting with some other part of your query to cause the error.   That said, the code you have posted will not achieve your stated goal, either.

Comment: This is because you are mixing datatypes which you can't do in a single column.

Comment: I updated and EDIT to show full select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that it is possible for the line you posted to simply have Ryder_Price as a value, which is a decimal type.  And then you are trying to concatenate it to a string.

To acheive your stated goal:

> I want to check for a value in a table to see if it's null.
>
> If so, I just want output to be '0.000'; otherwise, I'd like the
>   actual value which must be converted to a varchar field.

Try this:

```
convert(varchar(max),isnull(Ryder_Price,'0.000'))
```